# How to get mean of a raster with rasterio?

Tags: raster, rasterio

I'm trying to get NDVI mean for each block of a ranch.
I start with cropping my raster for each block and it's work well.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, sys, shutil
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio
import rasterio.tools.mask
import fiona

blocks_path = sys.argv[1]
ndvi_path = sys.argv[2]

blocks = gpd.read_file(blocks_path) # Lecture du shape blocks
blocks_crs = blocks.crs # Lecture du SRC de blocks
ndvi = rasterio.open(ndvi_path) # Lecture du raster ndvi

path = os.path.dirname(blocks_path) # Chemin du dossier contenant les blocks
blocks_name = os.path.basename(blocks_path).replace('.shp', '')
os.chdir(path) # Change le répertoire courant pour le répertoire des blocks

raster = rasterio.open(ndvi_path) # Ouverture du raster
crs_work = raster.crs # Lecture du crs
raster.closed # Fermeture du raster

blocks = gpd.read_file(blocks_path) # Ouverture du shape
blocks = blocks.to_crs(crs_work) # Reprojection avec le crs du raster

if os.path.exists('{0}/reprojected'.format(path)):
    shutil.rmtree('{0}/reprojected'.format(path))
os.mkdir('{0}/reprojected'.format(path))

if os.path.exists('{0}/ndvi_masked'.format(path)):
    shutil.rmtree('{0}/ndvi_masked'.format(path))
os.mkdir('{0}/ndvi_masked'.format(path))

for i, row in blocks.iterrows():
    block = blocks.loc[i:i] # Sélection de chaque parcelle
    block.crs = crs_work
    block_id = block['block_id'].loc[i]
    reproject_path = '{0}/reprojected/{1}_{2}_reproject.shp'.format(path, blocks_name, block_id) # Création du path du shape reprojeté
    block.to_file(reproject_path) # Enregistrement du shape

    with fiona.open(reproject_path, 'r') as shapefile:
        features = [feature['geometry'] for feature in shapefile]

    with rasterio.open(ndvi_path) as src:
        out_image, out_transform = rasterio.tools.mask.mask(src, features,
                                                            crop=True)
        out_meta = src.meta.copy()

    out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                     "height": out_image.shape[1],
                     "width": out_image.shape[2],
                     "transform": out_transform})
    with rasterio.open("ndvi_masked/ndvi_{0}_masked.tif".format(block_id), "w", **out_meta) as dest:
        dest.write(out_image)
```

And now I'm trying to get mean of each block's raster following this method : [Generating summary statistics for each band](https://mapbox.s3.amazonaws.com/playground/perrygeo/rasterio-docs/cookbook.html?highlight=mean)

```
with rasterio.open("ndvi_masked/ndvi_{0}_masked.tif".format(block_id)) as rst:
        array = rst.read()

for band in rst:
        print(band.mean())
```

But it returns me `-inf`

So I look values in each band :

```
print(array[0])
print(array[1])
```

It returns

```
[[ -3.40282347e+38  -3.40282347e+38  -3.40282347e+38  -3.40282347e+38
   -3.40282347e+38  -3.40282347e+38  -3.40282347e+38  -3.40282347e+38]
 [ -3.40282347e+38   4.47609603e-01   4.52652454e-01   4.71725464e-01
    4.85391140e-01   4.81654584e-01  -3.40282347e+38  -3.40282347e+38]
 [ -3.40282347e+38   4.40300375e-01   4.59738970e-01   4.60827261e-01
    4.70019341e-01   4.73709375e-01   4.85469282e-01  -3.40282347e+38]
 [ -3.40282347e+38   4.37375754e-01   4.63509887e-01   4.66958225e-01
    4.57718790e-01   4.64589924e-01   4.83453244e-01  -3.40282347e+38]
 [ -3.40282347e+38   4.48292911e-01   4.68704522e-01   4.61218506e-01
    4.49523330e-01   4.63508934e-01   4.90333110e-01  -3.40282347e+38]
 [ -3.40282347e+38   4.51518118e-01   4.62313980e-01   4.60417688e-01
    4.54413205e-01   4.53313977e-01   4.84736353e-01  -3.40282347e+38]
 [ -3.40282347e+38   4.42874253e-01   4.43333328e-01   4.47487503e-01
    4.47081149e-01   4.38679248e-01   4.73487496e-01  -3.40282347e+38]
 [ -3.40282347e+38  -3.40282347e+38  -3.40282347e+38  -3.40282347e+38
   -3.40282347e+38   4.69480366e-01  -3.40282347e+38  -3.40282347e+38]]

[[ -3.40282347e+38  -3.40282347e+38  -3.40282347e+38  -3.40282347e+38
   -3.40282347e+38  -3.40282347e+38  -3.40282347e+38  -3.40282347e+38]
 [ -3.40282347e+38   2.55000000e+02   2.55000000e+02   2.55000000e+02
    2.55000000e+02   2.55000000e+02  -3.40282347e+38  -3.40282347e+38]
 [ -3.40282347e+38   2.55000000e+02   2.55000000e+02   2.55000000e+02
    2.55000000e+02   2.55000000e+02   2.55000000e+02  -3.40282347e+38]
 [ -3.40282347e+38   2.55000000e+02   2.55000000e+02   2.55000000e+02
    2.55000000e+02   2.55000000e+02   2.55000000e+02  -3.40282347e+38]
 [ -3.40282347e+38   2.55000000e+02   2.55000000e+02   2.55000000e+02
    2.55000000e+02   2.55000000e+02   2.55000000e+02  -3.40282347e+38]
 [ -3.40282347e+38   2.55000000e+02   2.55000000e+02   2.55000000e+02
    2.55000000e+02   2.55000000e+02   2.55000000e+02  -3.40282347e+38]
 [ -3.40282347e+38   2.55000000e+02   2.55000000e+02   2.55000000e+02
    2.55000000e+02   2.55000000e+02   2.55000000e+02  -3.40282347e+38]
 [ -3.40282347e+38  -3.40282347e+38  -3.40282347e+38  -3.40282347e+38
   -3.40282347e+38   2.55000000e+02  -3.40282347e+38  -3.40282347e+38]]
```

I don't understand values with e+38, cause ndvi is between -1 and 1.
Somebody can help, cause i'm lost...

*** I found how to delete 2nd band. I tick alpha channel box... ***

Comment: The 'e+n' and 'e-n' syntax translates to your number times 10^n and 10^(-n) respectively. You can think of it as how many places you move the decimal. i.e. `2.5e+3 = 2500` and `2.5e-3 = 0.025` move the decimal 3 places right and left respectively. This doesn't explain why your NDVI values are like they are...

Comment: @RoperMaps Yes my issue isn't to understand what means e+38 but why this kind of values for ndvi raster...

Comment: OK, so then you need to go back to your original NDVI's and check the data coming from them. It maybe that the values have been stretched in some way.

Comment: Weird cause in QGIS raster values are pretty good...

Comment: It looks like all your inf values are at the boundaries of your arrays. Probably has something to do with your reprojecting of the arrays. Do they look OK if you don't reproject them?

Comment: Ok it's nodata values ! I found how to change it but which value I can put to not influence mean ???

Comment: Set NaNs to "np.nan" then use np.nanmean when taking the average.